# Interact with webpage Beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 2.7 with beautifulsoup and urllib2, I'm trying to scrap this page: [angel.co/companies](http://angel.co/companies)
As you see it shows a list with companies and it ends with a button "More" to show the others. As you click the button, more companies appear to watch and it creates a new  tag with the new list of resutls. The button is in this div: `<div class="more" data-page="2">More</div>` and each time you click it the data-page increases.
I'd like to know if it's possible to scrap this page completely (so it clicks the "More" button each time it arrives to the end). I suppose it is scrapping the css and changing it but I never did so and I haven't found information about this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do you could [use their API](https://angel.co/api) for this. If you are not sure what it is and how to use it, try googling around for an answer. [Here's one for starters.](https://gigaom.com/2010/10/29/using-apis-not-quite-as-hard-as-it-looks/)

Comment: Actually, that was just an example of webpage, I'd like to learn how to do this in other websites too.